How can I correctly authenticate a user Login Request with Google Firebase in .NET8+ hybrid mudblazor project?
I'm trying to integrate Firebase Authentication into my MudBlazor hybrid application. I'm using the Firebase JavaScript SDK and have initialized Firebase correctly in my index.html file. However, when I try to call a JavaScript function ( firebaseLogin ) from my Blazor component using JSRuntime.InvokeAsync , I get the following error:
Error: Could not find 'firebaseLogin' ('firebaseLogin' was undefined). 
Error: Could not find 'firebaseLogin' ('firebaseLogin' was undefined). 
at http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:734 
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) 
at l.findFunction (http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:702) 
at b (http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:5445) 
at http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3238 
at new Promise (<anonymous>) 
at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:3201) 
at Object.oi [as invokeJSJson] (http://localhost:5071/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:165225) 
at http://localhost:5071/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.6.j0mgruvzhc.js:3:178364 
at Tl (http://localhost:5071/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.6.j0mgruvzhc.js:3:179198)


Here's my index.html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Intuitive Recruitment</title>

    <!-- Preconnect to Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    
    <!-- Link to New Amsterdam from Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Amsterdam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'New Amsterdam', sans-serif;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Firebase SDKs -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script> <!-- Add Firebase Auth SDK -->

    <!-- Firebase Configuration -->
    <script src="firebase-config.js"></script> <!-- This file will contain your Firebase config -->

    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // Define the firebaseLogin function
        window.firebaseLogin = async (email, password) => {
            try {
                const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                const idToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();
                return idToken; // Return the ID token
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Firebase login error:", error);
                return null; // Return null if there's an error
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Blazor WebAssembly loader -->
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" asp-route-debug="true"></script>
</body>
</html>


I've confirmed that my firebase-config.js file is in the correct location. Ive checked the network panel in the developer console in google chrome and the firebase-config.js is not loading. There are no errors in the console either. The errors that are displayed, appear underneath the login button when the login button is pressed. Ive checked the console and there are no errors there.
